# how to compare a vector of length 1 with a vector of length greater than 1?

Tags: r

```r
vec1<- c(4)
vec2<-c(1,3,4,5)
vec1==vec2
```

output:[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

expected output: [1] TRUE

I want to return "TRUE" once only if a single value in vec2 is equal to a value in vec1... how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap with `any` to check for any `TRUE` element

```
any(vec1 == vec2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or instead of `==`, use `%in%`, which returns the length of the object on the lhs of `%in%`

```
vec1 %in% vec2
#[1] TRUE
```